# Easy cancellation of a task?

Tags: c#, task, cancellation

In my application, I have a button that will start a long running Task. In order that the GUI is not blocked, I do this in a Background Task. The following function is executed when the button is pressed:

```
private async void StartButtonHandler()
{
 await Task.Run(() =>
 {
  FirstAction();
  SecondAction();
  ThirdAction();
 });
}
```

Now I want to make this cancellable. I added a second button and modified the Code like this:

```
private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;

private async void StartButtonHandler()
{
 tokenSource?.Dispose();
 tokenSource = new CanncellationTokenSource();
 CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;
 await Task.Run(() =>
 {
  FirstAction();
  if(token.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
   return;
  }
  SecondAction();
  if(token.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
   return;
  }
  ThirdAction();
 });
}

private void CancelButtonHandler()
{
 tokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

This works fine, but it becomes were uncomfortable when the code becomes longer. Imagine that the FirstAction() function calls again several long-running functions and I want to add a place to cancel the task inside FirstFunction(). I would have to write the function FirstAction() like this:

```
private void FirstAction(CancellationToken token)
{
 FirstSubAction();
 if(token.IsCancellationRequested)
 {
  return;
 }
 SecondSubAction();
 if(token.IsCancellationRequested)
 {
  return;
 }
 ThirdSubAction();
 if(token.IsCancellationRequested)
 {
  return;
 }
 FourthSubAction();
}
```

So my question is: Is there some pattern that helps me to make this code more clearly? In my opinion, all these if statements distract from what's really going on.

Comment: That's what [`CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested?view=netframework-4.8) is for.  You can call this from an inner method and handle the `OperationCanceledException` at an outer level.

Comment: You can try *throwing exception* via `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` which can be useful when you want to know has the task *been completed* or *not* (has been *interrupted* on some stage)

Comment: I think the problem is that he wants some way to enclose a  chunk of code in a scope  and if someone uses `Cancel` on the  `TaskCancellationSource` the task will end.Unfortunately you can not `cancel` tasks from the outside , and you can only cancel them from the inside using `IsCancellationRequested` in conjuction with `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite that method in the following way, do note that to make it working all subactions should have the same method signature `void methodName(CancellationToken token)`.

```
private void FirstAction(CancellationToken token)
{
    Action<CancellationToken>[] actions = new Action<CancellationToken>[]{FirstSubAction, SecondSubAction, ThirdSubAction, ForthSubAction};
    foreach(Action<CancellationToken> action in actions)
    {
        if(token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
        action(token);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, I am looking for something like this. I have to check if I will be able to apply it to my real code. One extension to the answer: If you have different types of parameters in your functions, you can use lambda expressions: `Action[] actions = new Action[] { () => FirstSubAction("some string"), () => SecondSubAction(5), …};`

Comment: Nice idea, if you need diferent signatures you could edit your question and then either edit my answer or mention me so I can add your suggestion to my answer. At the moment I am leaving the most simple code.

Comment: I think that really makes the code a lot harder to follow, compared to just having `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` in the appropriate places (along with an outer handler for `OperationCanceledException`).

Comment: @MatthewWatson With your suggestion you would make "return if cancelled" into a "exception if cancelled + try/catch". Not my personal preference, because not only the code would have a similar structure OP was trying to avoid but also would have the extra cost of exceptions. Anyway you could propose another answer, the more different ways to accomplish a problem the better it would fit similar use cases.

Comment: One issue you'll have with using `IsCancellationRequested` rather than `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` is that it's impossible to tell if the task actually responded to the cancellation - although a lot of code doesn't care about that. (You can't check the state of the token, because that could have been set to cancelled just as the method is returning, so the method wasn't cancelled even though the token was.) As ever, your mileage may vary.